# Artifacts disappearing from maven central?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-central

Over the course of the last few hours, the following artifact seems to have disappeared from maven central:

`groupId: org.apache.jena
 artifactId: jena-jdbc
 version: 1.1.0`

It was there, my project was building just fine, then all of a sudden:

`$ curl -I "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-jdbc/1.1.0/jena-jdbc-1.1.0.jar"
 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 Server: nginx
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Length: 168
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 08:55:35 GMT
 Via: 1.1 varnish
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-Served-By: cache-iad2121-IAD
 X-Cache: MISS
 X-Cache-Hits: 0
 X-Timer: S1411376135.762460,VS0,VE53`

What's going on here? Will it mysteriously come back? What can cause this to happen? Has anyone seen this before?

FWIW: The workaround is easy, download and install locally... but why did it go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong URL.

Didn't you mean e.g. jena-jdbc-core?

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-jdbc-core/1.1.0/

Comment: Just to clarify, `jena-jdbc` exists as well, but it's only pom project, doesn't have a jar.

Comment: Bah... I certainly feel silly. I don't need the `jena-jdbc-core` dependency, I also don't need the `jena-jdbc` dependency as it's POM only. Everything is A-OK with just the flavor of the driver that I need (`jena-jdbc-driver-remote` in my case). Thanks for catching my boneheaded mistake. DOH!